# cordova platform add: adding second platform removes node modules for existing plugins and platforms

Tags: cordova, npm, cordova-ios, cordova-android

I am basically doing the following:

```sh
cordova plugin add pluginA 
cordova plugin add pluginC
cordova plugin add pluginX
cordova platform add android
```

This installs the plugins and cordova-android@8.1.0 which is there in node modules along with pluginA, pluginB and pluginC once the add completes. I then do:-

```sh
cordova platform add ios@5
```

Installs cordova-ios, but removes cordova-android module and all the plugin modules from node_modules. Doesn't remove the platform, just the node modules.

With npm timing turned on, I can see it running the following npm command, and that npm command removes cordova-android and the plugins

```
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'cordova-ios@5',
1 verbose cli   '--production',
1 verbose cli   '--save-exact'
1 verbose cli ]
```

I have managed to reproduce the issue with a basic project setup, based on my real project cut to the bone:

```sh
mkdir issue && cd issue && {
  mkdir www
  echo '{}' > build.json
  cat >config.xml <<-EOF
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <widget id="com.example.mobile.test" version="0.0.1" android-versionCode="1"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0"
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <name>Test Client</name>
    <description>Test Client</description>
    <author email="user@email.com" href="http://www.yourcompany.com">Your Company</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <engine name="ios" spec="5" />
  </widget>
  EOF

  cordova --verbose platform add --save android
  cordova --verbose platform add --save ios@5

  test ! -d node_modules/cordova-android \
    && echo "cordova-android has been removed"
}
```

From `~/.npm/_logs` I can see the following npm commands are executed:

```sh
/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/npm view cordova-custom-config --json
/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/npm install cordova-custom-config --production --save
/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/npm install cordova-android@^8.0.0 --production --save-exact
/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/npm install cordova-ios@5 --production --save-exact
```

And from the npm log for the install cordova-ios@5 can see that npm decided to uninstall cordova-android

```
97 silly diffTrees remove cordova-android@8.1.0
98 silly diffTrees remove cordova-custom-config@5.1.0
```

NPM Version Information:

```
2 info using npm@6.14.8
3 info using node@v14.15.1
```

Also, for reference, using these commands to enable npm logging:

```sh
npm config set timing true
npm config set logs-max 10000
```

Comment: Have you tried deleting your node_modules and removing your Cordova platform, before installing the npm dependencies and Cordova platform and plugins? Does it work if you add the Cordova platforms before and afterwards install the Cordova plugins?

Comment: I am starting from an empty folder (just www, config.xml and build.json) each time. I have since reproduced this without any plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour is triggered by having a single `<engine/>` node in `config.xml`. Specifying both engines, or no engines at all, the modules are not removed when adding a second platform.

```xml
  <engine name="ios" spec="5" />
  <engine name="android" spec="8" />
```

The following `config.xml` works.

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.example.mobile.test" version="0.0.1" android-versionCode="1"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <name>Test Client</name>
  <description>Test Client</description>
  <author email="user@email.com" href="http://www.yourcompany.com">Your Company</author>
  <content src="index.html" />
</widget>
```

Quite why the `<engine/>` node is influencing `npm` to remove those modules I have no idea.

The following script works, leaving both the plugins and cordova platforms intact.

```sh
mkdir issue && cd issue && {
  mkdir www
  echo "{}" >build.json

  cat >config.xml <<-EOF
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <widget id="com.example.mobile.test" version="0.0.1" android-versionCode="1"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0"
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <name>Test Client</name>
      <description>Test Client</description>
      <author email="user@email.com" href="http://www.yourcompany.com">Your Company</author>
      <content src="index.html" />
    </widget>
  EOF

  cordova plugin add cordova-custom-config
  cordova platform add --save android
  cordova platform add --save ios@5
}
```